# just installed kali linux, forgot username i entered in installation

Tags: linux, debian, bypass

I just reinstalled Kali Linux 2020.2 because I had too many problems earlier.
I created a new username and password in the Kali Linux installation. I wrote the password to a file, but already forgot the username. I'm wondering if there's a way to dump system users. I'm currently stuck on login. If anyone can help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: Probably easiest to just reinstall Kali again. Kali V2020 fresh install (not upgrade) has no Root user.  It uses first user plus sudo authority to do things.

Comment: This works with Ubuntu, not sure if it works with Kali. Use live CD and `cat /etc/passwd`. The list of all users is before the `=` sign. I assume you can recognize your own username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset your password through `init=/bin/bash` trick.

- First boot Kali Linux GRUB menu.
- Now in GRUB menu, select "Kali GNU/Linux" and press "e".
- Then in the next screen find a line starting with "linux".
- There replace "ro" with "rw" and replace "quiet" with "init=/bin/bash".
- Now type command `mount` in the shell.
- And then type command `passwd user_name` to reset password.
- Now reboot with `exec /sbin/init`.

Hope that helps

**Note: If you have forgot your username to then you can run `cat /etc/passwd` to search for your username, or to filter only usernames run `awk -F: '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd`**

Comment: He forgot the username too... Might want to add that in there. ;)

Comment: I think the author knows the password but not the user name

Comment: @John,acejavelin see the update, Maybe `cat /etc/passwd`/`awk -F: '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd` and search for the username??

Answer (score 0):

Run `cat /etc/passwd` and see which one is your username. It's likely you'll see a lot of entries, but this is normal, because a lot of daemons run as their own user.